# Personalizar os dados de um array da sessão em codeigniter

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, session, login

Estou tentando criar um array com os dados que eu recupero do banco de dados, meu código está assim

```
$usuario = $this->input->post("usuario");
$senha = $this->input->post("senha");
$this->db->select('id','usuario','senha','tipo');
$this->db->from('usuario');
$this->db->where('usuario',$usuario);
$this->db->where('senha',MD5($senha));
$login = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Aqui eu faço a consulta no banco e recupero as informações em um array e guardo no $login.
Dai eu verifico se este array não é vazio para autenticar a sessão

```
 if ( is_array($login) && count($login) == 1) {
      $this->session->set_userdata("logado", 1);
      $this->load->view("admin/redireciona");
    } else {
//caso a senha/usuário estejam incorretos, então mando o usuário novamente para a tela de login com uma mensagem de erro.
        $dados['erro'] = "Usuário/Senha incorretos";
        $this->load->view("login", $dados);
    }
```

Ao fazer este procedimento, eu verifico se o usuário e a senha estão corretos no banco e autorizo o login, caso de errado, informo o erro. Agora queria passar alguns dados para poder utilizar futuramente dentro da aplicação, e é ai que eu estou tendo problemas.

```
$dadossessao = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'nome' => $this->input->post('usuario'),
            'tipo' => $this->input->post('tipo'),
            'logado' => 1
);
```

O 'id' e 'tipo' não estão retornando valores, o que eu faço para que estas variáveis recebam os dados que foram recuperados do bd.

PS:
Meu DB está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`usuario` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`senha` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`tipo` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `usuario` (`id`, `usuario`, `senha`, `tipo`) VALUES
(1, 'teste', MD5('teste'), 1);
```

Comment: Certo, já me toquei que o problema ta sendo a sintaxe do $this->input->post('...'), mas não estou conseguindo achar a sintaxe correta.

Comment: Troque `$this->input->post('id')` por `$login[0]['id']` e `$this->input->post('tipo')` por `$login[0]['tipo']` você não está passando esses valores via formulário e sim recuperando da sua consulta no banco de dados, logo é só pegar a variável que trás esses dados e por eles na sua função que cria a sessão.

Comment: @William Novak deste jeito deu o erro 'Function name must be a string'. A variável não recebeu os dados do banco. Como comentei, eu sei que o problema está sendo esta declaração, mas como não sou muito bom com php, estou tendo esta dificuldade.

Comment: Dá um `print_r($login)` e veja se a variável realmente está pegando o dados do banco de dados pela sua consulta.

Comment: @William Novak Acabei de fazer o teste aqui, e a variável $login não está recebendo dado algum realmente, por isso que não estou conseguindo recuperar os dados do usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, criei um model onde fazia a consulta e me retornava os dados, dai eu preenchia o array da sessão.
Ficou assim o Controller:

```
$this->load->model('login');
    $usuario = $this->input->post("usuario");
    $senha = MD5($this->input->post("senha"));
    $login = $this->login->autenticar($usuario, $senha);

    if ($login) {
        $dados = array(
            'logado' => 1,
            'usuario' => $login['usuario'],
            'tipo' => $login['tipo'],
            'id' => $login['id']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($dados);
        $this->load->view("admin/redireciona");
    } else {
        $dados['erro'] = "Usuário/Senha incorretos";
        $this->load->view("login", $dados);
    }
```

E o model assim:

```
public function autenticar($usuario, $senha){

    $this->db->where('usuario', $usuario);
    $this->db->where('senha', $senha);
    $log = $this->db->get('usuario')->row_array();
    return $log;

}
```

Espero que ajude a outros que tenham este problema também.

Comment: Acho que minha contribuição não valeu de nada, nem um pontinho do povo que visualizou...